# Jump to class within div with overflow:scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a scrolling div and I want to jump to the first class when I type in a search box.  Currently, I have the scrolling div and text highlighting all works (I type in the search box and text in the scrollable div goes yellow)

```
<p>Search: <input type="text" id="text-search" /> <span>Found string: <span id="string-count">add a search term</span></span></p>
<pre><code style="overflow:scroll; height:400px;" id="json">my content is here</code></pre>
```

I have a class count working too.

What I now what to do is jump to the first class within the scrolling div.

Something like the below scrolls, but it moves the whole page

```
$(".highlight").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

What do I need to not move the page, just the text in the scroll area

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Grant

Answer (score 0):

I slept on it, and did some more research and this plugin seems to do what I needed

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Called like this
$('#json').scrollTo('.highlight');

Thanks

Grant